samba-tool command line fails when Fedora 40 python3.12 site-package samba attempts to import ldb
After installing all the samba related packages (see first block below) using dnf on my new Fedora 40 machine, including samba-tools, the samba-tool execution on the command line fails per the second block below.  I've attempted to find and install (using dnf) anything related to ldb, I've attempted to find a python module named 'ldb', all to no avail.
First block - installing samba and related libraries / tools / python modules
[userid@myhost]# /usr/bin/dnf reinstall python3-samba libldbsamba python-ldb python-samba* samba samba-dc samba-client krb5-workstation samba-tools...

successfully reinstalls: krb5-workstation python-ldb-devel-common python3-samba python3-samba-dc python3-samba-devel python3-samba-test samba samba-client samba-client-libs samba-dc samba-tools
Second block - ImportError during initial execution of samba-tool:
[userid@myhost]# /usr/bin/samba-tool domain provision --use-rfc2307 --interactive --option="interfaces=lo winbridge" --option="bind interfaces only=yes"

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/bin/samba-tool", line 33, in <module>
    from samba.netcmd.main import samba_tool

File "/usr/lib64/python3.12/site-packages/samba/init.py", line 27, in <module>
    import ldb

ImportError: libtdb-ldb.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I did build and install ldb-2.9.1 earlier in this process when this error first occurred, but the conflicts with using 'make install' instead of dnf and/or rpms didn't go well - I ended up rescuing my Fedora system by reinstalling Fedora 40
Question: What am I missing / how do I properly install the module 'ldb' into the python site-package?  Or do I need to somehow override samba-tool?
